# Email Provider : dynamic content

Tags: php, email, provider

We are building a daily newsletter based on member preferences. The member can choose a city and some categories among a list of 10. Basically each email will be different. Each email is generated by our server.

We are unable to find a provider with an API that can do that. Would you have any solution that ensure a 99% delivery.

Thank you

Damien

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like you don't need a third party solution. Your question is vague, maybe i'm misunderstanding.

You can build a custom webapp/webpage in PHP for example that would issue a request to the DB, fetch out member data, and construct emails to send out. In the simplest of scenarios this can be done in about an hour. Delivery is basically guaranteed assuming email addresses are correct and the server and network have decent uptime.

Comment: Actually, in the filthy world of today's email, deliverability is a huge challenge.  Reverse DNS, consistent IPs of the sending domain, SPF records, corporate / ISP whitelists and blacklists all have a huge bearing on whether your mail gets through.  Sometimes it's just easier to have someone else deal with it...

Answer (score 0):

I built a similar service that emails users customized content based on preferences.  I used a service called Triggermail, by Sailthru.  I assemble the body html of the email on my server and then make an API call to them to actually send the mail to user.

They provide a control panel where you can define templates, upload lists of emails, and find out a (growing) number of statistics related to delivery, clickthrough, and they also handle opt-outs.  They have excellent delivery rates, integrate with Google Analytics by just ticking a checkbox, and have a pretty fair cpm.

http://sailthru.com/

I know the owner, and can provide an introduction, if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of an email service provider, this is not dynamic content but static content, as you're assembling each copy yourself.

You should ask providers for "triggered" or "real time" messaging via an API, and indicate you provide each copy. You'll most commonly find APIS with facilities where you set up a template and only pass in the variables that drive the personalization. From your use case, you should also be able to work with that (same result, different implementation). Both definitely exist on the marketplace, but whether you're an interesting client depends of how many of these you plan to deploy (and of course what the origin of your list, your privacy practices etc are).